# ExtractAssociatedIcon Displays Poor Quality Icon In ListView

Tags: c#, winforms

What I am trying to do is extract an icon for any giving file and display it in a list view. This works great, however it displays a poor quality icon with a black boarder around it. I have read about adding .ToBitmap at the and of the statement but that returns "Cannot convert method group 'ToBitmap' to non-delegate typ 'System.Drawing.Icon'. Did you intend to invoke this method?"

**Edit:** I should have phrased a question: Is there a better way of going about this?

```
Icon iconForFile = SystemIcons.WinLogo;
iconForFile = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(fileFullName);
_imageList1.Images.Add(iconName, iconForFile);

item.ImageKey = iconName;
listView1.Items.Add(item)
```

Comment: What is the `ImageSize` of your `_imageList1`? And have you set `listView1.LargeImageList`?

Comment: @Bolu Yes: `_imageList1.ImageSize = new Size(32, 32);` `listView1.LargeImageList = _imageList1;`

Comment: This is the one I've used (remember to get the large Icon if you want), hope it helps. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319350

Comment: I looked over that before, however it is a large chunk of code just to extract icons. I will give it a shot tonight since my options are looking slim. Thank you for the reply.

Comment: @Bolu I gave KB319350 a chance and the code works, however I still get that black boarder around the extracted icons : (

Comment: Make sure `_imageList1.ColorDepth` is set to `Depth32Bit`. sorry, I should point this out much earlier.

Comment: @Bolu Thank You!!! `_imageList1.ColorDepth = ColorDepth.Depth32Bit;` was the key player here. Icons look great now and it actually works with my original code: `iconForFile = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(fileFullName);` which will save me those two extra methods. Could you post this as the answer so I can credit you your rep?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Make sure `_imageList1.ColorDepth` is set to `Depth32Bit`